# How to show image half and mouse hover to move full image

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I created my bootstrap 4 website for the code below, so I got tired of showing half the image the first time because there was some conflict in my code and it does not work properly when I move the mouse after moving the whole image from right to left. Anyone knows how to do it right

**[Example PROTOTYPE HERE](https://xd.adobe.com/view/1b312583-39fc-413b-8372-361acc66c538-4e62/?fullscreen)**

Thanks

```css
.moving-left
{

    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    transform: translateX(0px);

}
.moving-left:hover
{
    transform: translateX(-80px);
}

.moving-left button
{
    left: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row mb-75">
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <div class="anime-image-wrapper">
                                <div class="feature-image-wrap ml--55">
                                    <div class="moving-left">
                                    <img src="https://colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/best-bootstrap-admin-templates.jpg" class="wow zoom" alt="astriol feature">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <span class="circle" data-parallax='{"y": -70}'></span>

                                <div class="anime-dot">
                                    <img src="media/feature/dot.png" alt="astrion dot">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.anime-image-wrapper -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
```

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand the question: you have an image you want halfway hidden by default, which then slides fully into view when hovered over?

Comment: @AdamJ actually that's right, can you know some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is what you're looking for, the question is not very clear.
But here is what i understood: An image on the left (to the half of it's size) that slides right when hovered.

```css
.moving-left
{

    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    transform: translateX(-50vw);

}
.moving-left:hover
{
    transform: translateX(0vw);
}

.moving-left button
{
    left: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row mb-75">
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <div class="anime-image-wrapper">
                                <div class="feature-image-wrap ml--55">
                                    <div class="moving-left">
                                    <img src="https://colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/best-bootstrap-admin-templates.jpg" class="wow zoom" alt="astriol feature">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <span class="circle" data-parallax='{"y": -70}'></span>

                                <div class="anime-dot">
                                    <img src="media/feature/dot.png" alt="astrion dot">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.anime-image-wrapper -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
```

Comment: hello there . I mean like this https://xd.adobe.com/view/1b312583-39fc-413b-8372-361acc66c538-4e62/?fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to use the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property, the [inset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/inset()) function and the [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-class.

```css
#image-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
}

#img1 {
  clip-path: inset(0 50% 0 0);
}

#img2 {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 50% 0);
}

img:hover {
  clip-path: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-wrapper">
  <img id="img1" src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png" />
  <img id="img2" src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: hello there . I mean like this https://xd.adobe.com/view/1b312583-39fc-413b-8372-361acc66c538-4e62/?fullscreen